# How to detect that my app is the top-most window

Tags: windows, winforms

There are seven ways in which a 'dormant' application can become the 'active' one, based upon the combinations of whether it is minimised or simply obscured, and whether it is re-activated via alt-tab, a mouse-click of its icon, re-activated by it being sent a windows message from another program, or is simply 'discovered' to be the top-most application on the desktop when the application obscuring it is closed (or minimised).

In all cases I need to know that my app is now the active (e.g. top-most on the desktop) application so that I can refresh its data from the database.

I do know that apps 'know' when they are the top-most, as I can see the border changing to the active colour as soon as they become top-most.

If I trap WM_ACTIVATE_APP messages, this works most of the time, but doesn't seem to when my app was minimised and is restored to the active state.

I need to be told that my app is now top-most and active before the user does anything.

Any suggestions? Thanks, Dave

Comment: If an inactive application simply becomes uncovered and doesn't become active as a result, its border won't change. I presume you are asking about how to detect this case in particular (since if the application does become active you'll get WM_ACTIVATE_APP). I don't think this is anything to do with whether the application is top-most. Perhaps you should update your question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating, I found the cause and solution to my problem.

I found out that the `WM_ACTIVATEAPP` message was being sent (and received) OK, but this happened while the app was still in it minimized state (i.e. before it was restored).

Because I had an `if` test to not do anything when the app is minimized ( which is pointless as the user wouldn't see the results!), no action was being taken.

The `WM_ACTIVATEAPP` message *is* sent when the app gets 'uncovered', and that is okay since the app isn't minimized.

I now also respond to the `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` which gets fired upon restore,
and this combination seems to cover all seven ways in which my app can be re-activated.

Comment: The problem with not updating the question is that it makes it hard for someone else with the same problem to understand that the solution might be here. So please edit the question. Don't forget also to accept the answer that helped you (even if it's your own). I'll then delete any comments/answers I've made that are no longer relevant. (I'm still not clear whether you *really* want to refresh the data when it becomes visible, or when the application receives focus. These are two different things.)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

After such a time has elapsed that the data from the database should be considered out of date, call InvalidateRect() on your window (or the WinForms equivalent). If your window is not obscured it will get an immediate WM_PAINT. But if the window is completely obscured, it shouldn't get the WM_PAINT until the OS actually needs to display it - i.e. when the obscuring window is moved. Refresh the data from the database in response to the WM_PAINT message.

It turns out [Raymond Chen blogged about this back in 2003](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/08/29/54728.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach won't work. The amount of time for the data to become out-of-date is highly variable, and is dependent upon activities taken place within other applications. Therefore, the only sensible time to perform a refresh within my app is when the user 'comes back to' my app.